# audio capture plugin doesn't work in ionic view app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

```
var options = { limit: 1, duration: 3 };
navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, options);
```

The `org.apache.cordova.media-capture 0.3.6 "Capture"` works in the simulation. That will show a recording UI.

But after I uploaded the app to Ionic View. It doesn't work in Ionic View app.

Comment: I builded apk file and install it to my phone, it works. I guess Ionic View just can't run the native plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture plugin is not yet supported by ionic view.

Please see the list of supported plugins in this [link](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/view-usage).

Have answered the similar issue in [ngCordova capture not working on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947830/ngcordova-capture-not-working-on-device/31956483?noredirect=1#comment51828282_31956483)