# ngCordova capture not working on device

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ngcordova

I'm am attempting to record audio using Ionic and ngCordova.

Here is my code: 
    $scope.captureAudio = function() {
    var options = { limit: 3, duration: 10 };

```
$cordovaCapture.captureAudio(options).then(function(audioData) {
  // Success! Audio data is here
  alert(audioData);
  console.log(audioData);
}, function(err) {
  // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
  alert(err);
});
};
```

When I run this in the emulator it works fine and brings up the voice recorder and when the recording is done it logs out the audioData.

When I upload it to ionic view and run it I get nothing. Not even an error.

Has anyone seen anything like this before ?

Thanks 
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$cordovaCapture plugin is not yet supported by ionic view.

Please see the list of supported plugins in this [link](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/view-usage).

You can run the code in device directly using run command.

> ionic run android